# How about storing the array indices in a map

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary

my program is using boost::unordered_map a lot, and the map has about 40 million entries. This program doesn't do insertion or deletion very often. It just randomly accesses entries using keys.

I'm wondering will it improve the performance (in terms of the speed of accessing entries) if I store my entry values (about 1 KB each) in a flat array (maybe an std::vector), and I use boost::unordered_map to store the mapping of keys to the indices to this array.

Thanks,
Cui

Comment: Maybe.  Would you be using the unordered_map _every_ time you wanted to find the index?  Because if so, that would be _slower_ than just an `unordered_map` by itself.  If not, then use an iterator into the unordered_map instead of the index.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that could seriously speed up things. In fact, that's what Boost `flat_map` is for :)

The docs relate: [Non-standard containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx)

> Using sorted vectors instead of tree-based associative containers is a well-known technique in C++ world. Matt Austern's classic article ***[Why You Shouldn't Use set, and What You Should Use Instead (C++ Report 12:4, April 2000, `PDF`)](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf)*** was enlightening:
>
> ...

This gives you more than you asked for because you don't even need the extraneous index. This gives you more locality of reference and a lower memory footprint. Most importantly, it gives you lower complexity (-> fewer bugs) and a drop-in replacement for `std::[unordered_]map` in terms of interface.

Comment: @MooingDuck There isn't. The OP doesn't want to be using a tree either... :) Of course, you're raising a valid point, although then the path would lead to Boost Intrusive (and possibly `multi_index_container<.., indexed_by<random_access<>, unordered_unique<...> >`)

Answer (score 0):

Storing the values in contiguous memory like std::vector provides, will increase cache locality. This can make a pretty big difference in performance but it depends on the access pattern.

If your hunting performance, remember the golden rule:
*always measure!*